# Youtube videos in a WinForms c# app: Listing playlists and controlling a video

Tags: c#, video, youtube

This question is about accessing YouTube content via a C# WinForms application.
The requirements are:

1. To retrieve the metadata for a playlist, or for all playlists from a given artist.
2. To embed video and play it from within the app, synced to external timing events.

Approaches we've thought of:

1. Use the YouTube Data API Protocol to retrieve playlists. There isn't a C# wrapper out there as far as we can tell, though that may be easy to do.
2. Use a WebBrowser to display the video - not sure how we'd control the video though.

Questions:

1. Are these the right approaches?
2. Is there C# wrapper for the YouTube Data API protocol?
3. What is the easiest way to embed the video and to control the video timing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try here:
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html

Comment: Thanks, that answers Question 2 about the C# wrapper for the Data API. The wrapper does not appear to include functionality to embed videos on a WinForm (Question 3) or to control its playback timing. How best can that be done? Cheers,

Comment: If you're willing to use the web browser control, it may be possible to use javascript to control the video. On the link I sent, if you look on the lower left side of the page you'll find "YouTube Player Tools", but here's the link: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

Comment: Thanks. We just found http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/21033/1954 which addresses the winforms to flash piece.